# sidebar navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, navigation

I'm building a sidemenu but am having some dificulty with my setup mostly due to Navigator and Scaffold(Messenger) restrictions. Basically what I want is that any routes inside the sidebar have their own ScaffoldMessenger, and when you close subpage results in closing the entire sidemenu that the latest page is visible wile sliding-out.

Here's the dartpad:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=0b9680d7d5ac1a23e6db7cd9e63443c6

- Using a popuproute to partially obscure the underlying screen with modalbarrier
- Since routes uses overlays which are direct decendands of Navigator/MaterialApp, the only point where routes are inside the route itself.
- Putting a ScaffoldMessenger inside the route basically causes every "page" to have their own unique state so the messages aren't preserved from going from a one subpage to other inside the side menu.
- You could work with a (nested) navigator but the public interfaces are lacking and best the behavior I seem to get out of it is that from a subpage, it first pop back to the home page, and then side menu closes.